# Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for input Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs-flux, reactjs

While creating a component in Reactjs with input fields error occurs
`Error: Parse Error: Line 47: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for input at http://localhost/chat-react/src/script.js:47:20 </div>`

```
var Main = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="card-action">
                <i class="mdi-action-account-circle prefix"></i>
                <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Sometimes the error comes from the `form`, which has non ending inputs.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

You need to close the input element with a `/>` at the end.

```
<input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate" />
```

Comment: Can I ask why?, (I'm new in this topic)

Comment: @pedro If a tag is empty (no children elements) this is a shorthand way to close the element without having to create a matching closing element. So instead of: `<div></div>` . you can just do `<div />`.

See here for more: https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#specifying-children-with-jsx

Comment: I had a `<br>` and this was causing the problem (it expected a `<br />` instead). This is weird because HTML5 specs advises to don't use the leading slash for self closing tags

Comment: @CristianTraìna It's important to remember that JSX is not HTML.  JSX is it's own thing. Behind the scenes everything is converted to `React.createElement` and it depends on the closing of each element to know how things are intended to be nested.

Answer (score 20):

It happens when we do not close a html tag.

Make sure all the html tags are closed.

In my case it was the `<br>` tag. It should be `<br />`.

Try temporarily removing piece of code until you find which html tag closing is missing.

Answer (score 9):

This error also happens if you have got the order of your components wrong.

Example: this wrong:

```
 <ComponentA> 
    <ComponentB> 

    </ComponentA> 
 </ComponentB>
```

correct way:

```
  <ComponentA> 
    <ComponentB>

    </ComponentB>  
  </ComponentA>
```

Answer (score 4):

All tags must have enclosing tags. In my case, the **hr** and **input** elements weren't closed properly.

Parent Error was: *JSX element 'div' has no corresponding closing tag*, due to code below:

```
<hr class="my-4">
<input
  type="password"
  id="inputPassword"
  class="form-control"
  placeholder="Password"
  required
 >
```

Fix:

```
<hr class="my-4"/>
<input
 type="password"
 id="inputPassword"
 class="form-control"
 placeholder="Password"
 required
/>
```

The parent elements will show errors due to child element errors. Therefore, start investigating from most inner elements up to the parent ones.

Answer (score 4):

You need to close the input element with  `/>` at the end. In React, we have to close every element. Your code should be:

```
<input id="whatever-id" type="text" class="validate" />
```

Comment: I think you meant `class="validate" />` instead of `class="validate/">` at the end

Answer (score 0):

You have to close all tags like ,  etc for this to not show.

Comment: Please provide an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post

Answer (score 0):

All these answers are valid but I had that issue multiple times today **with** well closed tags. If it happens to you, just abort and run `npm start` again.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the:

```
<h1>aergawergerg</h1>
<h1>aergawergerg<h1/>
```

beginner error.